# How to show same view as iPhone on iPad instead of Split view?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I want the views to look the same on iPad as they do on iPhone.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without any code, but I bet you need to add `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to your NavigationView to not get it in split view mode on the iPad:

```
NavigationView {
  View1()
}.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```