# How do I set up a Navigation Link in SwiftUI on iPad so the buttons to navigate aren't in a sidebar?

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, swiftui

I'm working on an app that I would like to have the following navigation structure:
I want to have a welcome view with "Sign up" and "Sign in" buttons as most of apps have:

[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HudO.png)

I would like it to be such that this view doesn't have any navigation view bar at the top but the two buttons will navigate to the appropriate page e.g. the sign in page will ask for just login info, sign up page with ask the user for data.

[Sign In Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niHcm.png)

This however, while seemingly simple has been very confusing to achieve in SwiftUI when it comes to the iPad. When I try to use the Navigation Link it doesn't work as the links are stuck in a side bar that is hidden. I can't seem to find any solutions that work online as nearly everything is for the iPhone. Can anyone advise how to stop the links being placed in a sidebar on iPad?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're probably looking for `StackNavigationViewStyle` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012995/how-to-show-same-view-as-iphone-on-ipad-instead-of-split-view).

Comment: @jnpdx Ffs, thank you, I've been looking for something like this for 3 hours ‍♂️